# django ajax select add button

Tags: python, ajax, django

i installed django-ajax-select app,
its a wonderful app to have auto-complete option,
but after adding the form in admin.py 
the (+) button which is i can add new object  i attached a snapshot of an example,

i found a code which is splitting the value what are written by hooking clean method to override,
but in my case i just want the add button

```
def clean(self, value):
if value:
    lookup = get_lookup(self.channel)
    objs = lookup.get_objects( [value] )
    if objs:
        return objs[0]
    else:
        firstname, surname = value.split(" ")
        gender = self.channel.split("_")[0]
        new_skater = Skater(name=firstname, surname=surname, gender=gender)
        return new_skater
else:
    if self.required:
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
    return None
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the solution as its written wrongly in the documentation doc,

in admin.py
you should add this code, in my cade my admin calss is orderAdmin

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(orderAdmin,self).get_form(request,obj,**kwargs)
    autoselect_fields_check_can_add(form,self.model,request.user)
    return form
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows the exact same text as the accepted answer.

https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects#example

Either

1. your `Admin` class must inherit from `AjaxSelectAdmin`
2. you should use `AjaxSelectAdmin` as a mixin (multiple inheritance)
3. you can insert the `autoselect_fields_check_can_add` in your `get_form()`

You should only need to do the third case if you need to implement `get_form` for your own other purposes.  It's better to just inherit from `AjaxSelectAdmin`.

The other possible explanation for why you do get an ADD icon is that you don't have permission to add the object.  `autoselect_fields_check_can_add` checks using Django's standard admin permissions.